# PHP curl web scraper - scraping specific div

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I need to scrape list of products with the price from a this site.

What do I need to add to scripe only this list of products ( http://www.tehnomanija.rs/lcd-i-led--televizori)

This is my code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.tehnomanija.rs/lcd-i-led--televizori");
curl_exec ($curl);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

//parser
preg_match("<td class=\"product_list_cell\">")siU, $result, $matches1);


$suscriptores = $matches1[1][0];
echo "Suscriptores: " . $suscriptores;
print $result;
```

?>

Comment: You can just use any of html parsers (like simple_html_dom or so)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://github.com/tj/php-selector
it's essentially a wrapper for `DOMDocument` and `DOMxpath` which allows you to use css selectors like so

```
$elements = select_elements('div#someId', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong using regex for this task. Use xpath to retrive the needed dom nodes from the html. See [an example](https://webscraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php/).

I might also mention some of your mistakes:

1. You didn't include **RETURN_TRANSFER** in curl, [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).
2. You do not properly fetching by regex, [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

So the code should be smth like this:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.tehnomanija.rs/lcd-i-led--televizori");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

//parser
preg_match("/<td\s+class=\"product_list_cell\">(.*?)<\/td>/siU", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

$suscriptores = $matches[1];
echo "Suscriptores: " . $suscriptores;
print $result;
```

Yet, you still can't properly fetch by regex since the inner structure mixes `</td>`s of different levels. Your only way is xPath.
[image]